# Could not open connection to the HS2 server

Tags: docker, hive, data-science, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hiveserver2

I'm trying to connect to hive-server in my docker container with the command `beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000`, but i get the erros:

```
root@hive_server:/opt# beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
21/08/30 12:36:56 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 2.3.2 by Apache Hive
```

So i tryed to use `beeline -r`, and got this:

```
root@hive_server:/opt#
root@hive_server:/opt# beeline -r
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Beeline version 2.3.2 by Apache Hive
beeline> root@hive_server:/opt# beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
21/08/29 18:42:19 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to localhost:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 2.3.2 by Apache Hive
beeline>
```

with `beeline -help` i tryed to use another way to connect, which is `beeline -n username -p password -u jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10012` , and got this:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10012
21/08/30 12:54:25 [main]: WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to hs2.local:10012
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10012: java.net.UnknownHostException: hs2.local (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 2.3.2 by Apache Hiv
```

So idk what is going on and how to solve this problem. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research and help of colleagues (https://github.com/rbonela), found out that the problem was with permissions beeing denied in the directory: `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

So, the solution was kill all containers, edit docker-compose.yml file, on the hive-metastore-postgresql configuration section, change the directory `/var/lib/postgresql/data`to another one you like.

Test it out again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running hive server in a docker and trying to connect within the docker then you should not use host name as `localhost`. Use container name of hive server as hostname.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://<container_name>:10000
```

Comment: Hi @Mohana, thank you for your answer.

I tried this, but no results...

`beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hive-server:10000`

resulted in:

 `WARN jdbc.HiveConnection: Failed to connect to hive-server:10000
Could not open connection to the HS2 server. Please check the server URI and if the URI is correct, then ask the administrator to check the server status.
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hive-server:10000: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) (state=08S01,code=0)`

Comment: Is hive server running?  `hive --service hiveserver2`

Comment: That's a good question. The hive server soon or later stops, idk why.

Comment: here are: ` hive --service hiveserver2
2021-08-31 12:28:36: Starting HiveServer2
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-2.7.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]`

Comment: Which docker image are you using? did you set up on your local laptop?

Comment: I'm using a image provided by a course i'm taking. And yes, i have set up it.

Comment: I thought it would be the Java jdk, but i've intalled it and yet dont work.

Comment: If the container is stopping, try increasing memory of docker.

Comment: That's a good sugestion, i'll search how to do that. Thank you

Comment: It's just about a couple of clicks if you are using docker desktop.

Comment: Yeah... I discovered that i have to configurate a file:
"You are using the WSL 2 backend, so resource limits are managed by Windows.

You can configure limits on the memory, CPU, and swap size allocated to WSL 2 in a .wslconfig file."